# Design and analyze a linear time algorithm

Tags: algorithm, linear-search

> Design and analyze a linear time algorithm to determine whether
>   there exists an element in a list of n elements which repeats itself
>   at least n/10 times in the list.

How can I do this? I'm posting my own idea as an answer.

Comment: I assume you are not looking for an *average case* linear time algorithm (with additional `O(n)` space)? If so - it can be done by creating a hash based [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) of the elements and then iterating the histogram.

Comment: @amit please check my solution to see if it's correct, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume the elements are comparable.

Perform a [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) for the: n/10th, 2n/10th, ..., 9n/10th, 10(n/10)th smallest elements<sup>1</sup>

These are your candidates. Check the #occurrences for each of them, and if one of them repeats at least n/10 times the answer is `true`. Otherwise, it is `false`.

**Proof:**

If an element appears at least n/10 times, then it must "intersect" with `k*n/10` for some `k` (in a sorted list)<sup>2</sup>. Thus, this element will be chosen as a "candidate", and you will later discover (by counting) exactly how many times it appears, and will return `true`.

If no element is repeated `n/10` times, the algorithm will trivially return `false` in the last step of checking each candidate.

**Complexity**:

Each selection algorithm is `O(n)`, and it is done 10 times. Also for each candidate requires linear scan on the list, which is also `O(n)` totaling in `O(n)` overall—but with terrible constants.

---

**Explanations**:

(1)  Selection algorithm will find the element which would be in the index n/10, 2n/10,...9n/10 in a sorted list, and the algorithm itself is only `O(n)`

(2) Let's look at the example of `[1,2,..,100,100,..,100]` (11 times 100).
Note that the list is sorted and the  element 100 appears in: `list[9*n/10]` (index `9*n/10`). The idea of the selection algorithm is, that—even if you shuffle the list—`select(list,9*n/10)` will always return the same element—in this case 100—since it is the `9n/10`th element in the sorted list (this is what the algorithm does).

Now, you can see that for each element (let it be `e`) that repeats `n/10` times, there is some index `i` such that in the sorted version of the list, all elements in indices `i,i+1,...,i+n/10` will be `e`. One of these indices ***must*** be one of `k*n/10` for some `k` (convince yourself why!). Thus, the selection algorithm on `k*n/10` will yield `e`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but would you please explain a little bit more on "If an element appears at least n/10 times, then it must "intersect" with k*n/10 for some k (in a sorted list). " still not quite get the idea. and also to keep the question simple, let's assume the elements in the list are all integers.

Comment: @starcaller: I editted the answer (see edit, especially section 2). Hope it is more helpful.

Comment: @amit but what if we have an unsorted list.

Comment: Pedantic note: This (really good) solution supposes the sought element must appear more than `n/10` times in the list. If it can also appear exactly `n/10` times, the `k*n/10` points might miss it. Then one would use `k*n/11` for the selections.

Comment: @DanielFischer: You are correct, I first though we are looking for *more then* `n/10` - but from second read it seems not to be the case. Editting to also check the first and last elements.

Comment: Or, If you just add the n-th element (aka maximum) to the candidates, that suffices too for exactly `n/10` occurrences. Ah, duh, should finish reading the comments before adding, you already had that.

Comment: @starcaller: It does not matter, if the list was [100,100,...100,99,98,...,1] selection algorithm will yield the same result for checking the same innput (formally, for each `k` and for each `list`: `select(list,k) == select(shuffle(list),k)`)

Comment: You do have a thing for dashes xD

Comment: Clever!  Haven't seen this approach before.  Are there any other problems that can be solved efficiently like this, i.e. by looking what at a constant number of element positions would contain after sorting?

Answer (score 3):

Let me tell you a clever single pass algorithm to find a majority element (one with frequency higher than n/2) and you should see how to adapt it:

```
best = null
count = 0

foreach x in list:
   if (count == 0)
      count++
      best = x
   else if (best == x)
      count++
   else
      count--

return best
```

If there is a majority element, the above algorithm will find it (one pass, constant space).  Once you figure out how it works you will see how it can be adapted to the n/10 case.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to separate the list into 10/n groups, and each of the groups contains 10 elements, then perform a randomized selection sort on each group, this will take O(1)*O(n) time which is O(n).

Since to satisfy the requirements, the candidate element has to show in each of the n/10 groups, we can perform a scan for each of the 10 elements in the first group, which will take 10*O(n) time.

So the overall time for the algorithm is O(n)+10*O(n), which is still O(n).

But this will not work if the elements in the groups are something like following:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11
...
11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11
```

My algorithm will return that no such element exist while actually `11` is the element which appears more than n/10 times.

Comment: You claim "the candidate element has to show in each of the n/10 groups", but it could be missing from some and appear multiple times in others.  Also I think you mean "n/10 groups", not "10/n groups".

Comment: `the candidate element has to show in each of the n/10 groups` why? what about the list `[1,2,...,100,100,100,....,100]` (11 times 100). 100 won't appear in all lists, only in the last 2 lists

Comment: @amit haha, just edited my solution. yea, that's the tricky part which has kept me thinking for a long time, any idea how to make my solution working? thanks

Comment: @starcaller: (1) I tried to add my solution as an answer. (2) Your answer is wrong - so it will probably be downvoted. If you want it as a part of the question - you should edit and add this in the question itself - and not as an independent answer.